# Merging two Data Frames in R (Data frames not merging properly)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I've having a bit of a problem using the merge function in R for two data frames. I have two large data frames which have columns and data in common with each other, and that's what I use to merge them.

For instance, data frame 1 has columns "Instrument" , "RecordDate", "HourMinuteSecond", "MilliSecond", .... (and several other additional columns) while data frame 2 has columns "Instrument" , "RecordDate", "HourMinuteSecond", "MilliSecond", .... (and several other different columns compared to data frame 2). I now use the merge function as follows:

```
DataFrame3 <- merge(DataFrame2, DataFrame1, by=c("Instrument", "RecordDate","HourMinuteSecond","MilliSecond"))
```

And this gives me a new data frame. Now, the problem I'm having is that some between the data frames was not matched at all. For example, I found one section of data which was not matched properly:

```
> DataFrame1[120486,]
       Instrument RecordDate HourMinuteSecond MilliSecond 
120486        DTE   6/4/2012         16:10:27          42     

 > DataFrame2[65,]
   Instrument RecordDate HourMinuteSecond MilliSecond 
65        DTE   6/4/2012         16:10:27          42
```

(Note that there are other columns but I have omitted them).
I now compare these sections as if they are vectors. Firstly, I use the identical function to compare each value in each vector, and this gives the following:

```
> identical(DataFrame1[120486,1] ,DataFrame2[65,1])
[1] FALSE
> identical(DataFrame1[120486,2] ,DataFrame2[65,2])
[1] TRUE
> identical(DataFrame1[120486,3] ,DataFrame2[65,3])
[1] FALSE
> identical(DataFrame1[120486,4] ,DataFrame2[65,4])
[1] TRUE
```

From the identical function it appears as if the values in the columns "Instruments" and "HourMintuteSecond" are different from each other. Can anyone tell me what could be causing this issue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the dput output, hopefully this is what you were all referring to:

```
> dput(droplevels(DataFrame2[65,1:4]))
structure(list(Instrument = structure(1L, .Label = "DTE", class = "factor"), 
RecordDate = structure(1L, .Label = "6/4/2012", class = "factor"), 
HourMinuteSecond = structure(1L, .Label = "16:10:27", class = "factor"), 
MilliSecond = 42L), .Names = c("Instrument", "RecordDate", 
"HourMinuteSecond", "MilliSecond"), row.names = 65L, class = "data.frame")

> dput(droplevels(DataFrame1[120486,1:4]))
structure(list(Instrument = structure(1L, .Label = "DTE", class = "factor"), 
RecordDate = structure(1L, .Label = "6/4/2012", class = "factor"), 
HourMinuteSecond = structure(1L, .Label = "16:10:27", class = "factor"), 
MilliSecond = 42L), .Names = c("Instrument", "RecordDate", 
"HourMinuteSecond", "MilliSecond"), row.names = 120486L, class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the str() output:

```
> str(DataFrame1)
'data.frame':   317495 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Instrument      : Factor w/ 4 levels "CDD","DTE","ERA",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RecordDate      : Factor w/ 30 levels "5/18/2012","5/21/2012",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ HourMinuteSecond: Factor w/ 21763 levels "10:02:02","10:02:03",..: 14 14 14 17 19 22 24 25 25 25 ...
 $ MilliSecond     : int  26 57 158 70 73 8 926 448 457 458 ...
 $ L1BidPrice      : num  6.91 6.91 6.91 6.91 6.91 6.91 6.9 6.9 6.89 6.89 ...
 $ L1BidVolume     : int  520 504 504 504 504 508 20 4 20 20 ...
 $ L1AskPrice      : num  6.92 6.92 6.92 6.92 6.92 6.92 6.91 6.91 6.9 6.9 ...
 $ L1AskVolume     : int  3917 3917 3915 3932 3915 3915 3407 3407 13 30 ...
 $ Midquote        : num  6.92 6.92 6.92 6.92 6.92 ...

> str(DataFrame2)
'data.frame':   577 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Instrument       : Factor w/ 2 levels "DTE","ERA": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RecordDate       : Factor w/ 30 levels "5/18/2012","5/21/2012",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ HourMinuteSecond : Factor w/ 317 levels "10:02:10","10:02:21",..: 301 301 301 301 301 301 2 98 129 130 ...
 $ MilliSecond      : int  45 45 45 45 45 45 485 6 92 300 ...
 $ RecordType       : Factor w/ 1 level "TRADE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Price            : num  0.195 0.195 0.195 0.195 0.195 0.195 0.2 0.19 0.19 0.185 ...
 $ Volume           : int  2686 6350 6350 6350 1620 3064 1 13986 25000 23092 ...
 $ UndisclosedVolume: Factor w/ 1 level "\\N": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DollarValue      : num  524 1238 1238 1238 316 ...
 $ Qualifiers       : Factor w/ 4 levels "\\N","AC","Bi",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 3 4 ...
 $ BidID            : num  6.13e+18 6.13e+18 6.13e+18 6.13e+18 6.13e+18 ...
 $ AskID            : num  6.13e+18 6.13e+18 6.13e+18 6.13e+18 6.13e+18 ...
 $ BidOrAsk         : Factor w/ 1 level "\\N": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BuyerBrokerID    : int  229 229 229 229 229 229 236 129 229 112 ...
 $ SellerBrokerID   : int  297 210 210 210 110 157 229 229 299 229 ...
```

Comment: please post here using `dput` the 2 records which are not considered similar by `merge`

Comment: Maybe you have factors and the levels are not the same? Posting some `dput()`, e.g., `dput(DataFrame2[65,1:4])`, or if that's way too long `dput(droplevels(DataFrame2[65,1:4]))`, (and similar for the other row) would make everything clear.

Comment: More likely than not, if you run a `str()` on both of the frames, you will find that in column one, one data frame has them as a factor and the other character data (DTE) or on different levels, and the times in column three, they are shaped the same, but they may be in different time formats , or listed as factors at different levels....Use `str()` to figure it out!

Comment: Hi, I added dput output, I used the droplevels since the output was quite large and I can't seem to upload files. Also, I'll try out the str() function now :)

Comment: Regarding str(), how do the different levels affect the data? I'm not really familiar with the function or its meaning unfortunately. Do you have an idea of what I should do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# load data table library used for large data sets
library('data.table')

# convert factors into character
col1 <- colnames(df1)[sapply(df1, is.factor)]  # get columns that are factors for df1
col2 <- colnames(df2)[sapply(df2, is.factor)]  # get columns that are factors for df2

for(col in col1){   # df1
  set(df1, , col, as.character( df1[[col]] ) )    # for more info on set() function, read ?`:=`
}

for(col in col2){   # df2
  set(df2, , col, as.character( df2[[col]] ) )
}

# join two data frames by the selected columns in 'on' argument
setDT(df1)[df2, on = c('Instrument', 'RecordDate', 'HourMinuteSecond','MilliSecond')]   # setDT converts data frame to data table by reference
#    Instrument RecordDate HourMinuteSecond MilliSecond L1BidPrice L1BidVolume L1AskPrice L1AskVolume Midquote i.L1BidPrice i.L1BidVolume i.L1AskPrice i.L1AskVolume
# 1:        DTE   6/4/2012         16:10:27          42       6.91         520       6.92        3917     6.92            7             8            9            10
#    i.Midquote
# 1:         11

# merge function in data table is faster than the same function in base R function. You just convert data frame into data tables.
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
merge(df1, df2, by = c('Instrument', 'RecordDate', 'HourMinuteSecond','MilliSecond'))
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Instrument = "DTE", RecordDate = "6/4/2012", HourMinuteSecond = "16:10:27", 
                      MilliSecond = 42L, L1BidPrice = 6.91, L1BidVolume = 520, 
                      L1AskPrice = 6.92, L1AskVolume = 3917, Midquote = 6.92), .Names = c("Instrument", 
                                                                                          "RecordDate", "HourMinuteSecond", "MilliSecond", "L1BidPrice", 
                                                                                          "L1BidVolume", "L1AskPrice", "L1AskVolume", "Midquote"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame") 

df2 <- structure(list(Instrument = "DTE", RecordDate = "6/4/2012", HourMinuteSecond = "16:10:27", 
                      MilliSecond = 42L, L1BidPrice = 7, L1BidVolume = 8, L1AskPrice = 9, 
                      L1AskVolume = 10, Midquote = 11), .Names = c("Instrument", 
                                                                   "RecordDate", "HourMinuteSecond", "MilliSecond", "L1BidPrice", 
                                                                   "L1BidVolume", "L1AskPrice", "L1AskVolume", "Midquote"), row.names = 120486L, class = "data.frame")


df1
#    Instrument RecordDate HourMinuteSecond MilliSecond L1BidPrice L1BidVolume L1AskPrice L1AskVolume Midquote
# 1:        DTE   6/4/2012         16:10:27          42       6.91         520       6.92        3917     6.92

df2
#        Instrument RecordDate HourMinuteSecond MilliSecond L1BidPrice L1BidVolume L1AskPrice L1AskVolume Midquote
# 120486:        DTE   6/4/2012         16:10:27          42          7           8          9          10       11
```

Comment: Thanks for writing that out, I have another problem though - it turns out my R version isn't compatible with the data.table package (I have the latest version of R/R Studio so it won't install). Do you happen to know a way around it? I've been searching for a way around it but can't find anything yet :/

Comment: devtools doesn't install either, it doesn't appear to be compatible with my version of R as well :( Thanks for helping by the way

Comment: Putting getRversion() into RStudio gives ‘2.15.2’, and when I try and install data.table for example, it comes up with this message (a similar message comes up for devtools):           Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘data.table’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)

Comment: Thanks heaps! I think it worked properly! I just have one last question: In your answer above (the one with all the code) you have the line: setDT(df1)[df2, on = c('Instrument', 'RecordDate', 'HourMinuteSecond','MilliSecond')] and then after that you write: setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
merge(df1, df2, by = c('Instrument', 'RecordDate', 'HourMinuteSecond','MilliSecond')). Did you write that to show how there are two separate methods to merge data frames, or is that supposed to be the last step? (I hope my question is understandable)

Comment: Thanks heaps, I really appreciate all the help! Yes your method appears to give the correct results so it's even better in my opinion :)